# Can someone explain what's happening with my Python arrays?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm initializing these two lists and trying to replace the first 3 items in each list in two different ways.

```
b = c = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
print(b)
b[0] = 3; b[1] = 6; b[2] = 9
print(b)
c[0:2] = [3,6,9]
print(c)
```

but when I run the code I get the weird output below. I get what i expect for "b" but something totally expected for "c". Can someone explain to me why this is happening?

```
b = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
c = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
new b = [3, 6, 9, 8, 10, 12]
new c = [3, 6, 9, 9, 8, 10, 12]
```

Comment: `[0:2]` is only two items. Do you want `[0:3]`? Note that at all times `c==b`

Comment: This is a common beginner mistake in Python.  Assigning a list to a variable does *not* copy the list.  It merely creates a new *reference* to the list.  Any changes to the list are reflected in all references to it.  If you want to avoid that, you need to copy the list.  If you print `b` again after changing `c`, you'll see that it has changed as well, and that they are both the same.

Comment: @TomKarzes while true, that doesn't actually appear to be the behavior he's noticing.

Comment: @TomKarzes of course they are, but the behavior he's noticing is that `c[0:2]` is only two elements large, while he's trying to replace it with a list of length 3. I think the other behavior will bite him pretty immediately once he gets this working, but it's hard to say.

Comment: @AdamSmith Yes, agreed.  The range is off by one.  There are really two problems with the code.

Comment: @TomKarzes assuming OP is doing what we think he's doing, yes :-)

Comment: I got it, thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

`c[0:2]` means the first two elements, so essentially you're replacing `[3, 6]` with `[3, 6, 9]`. You should use

```py
c[0:3] = [3, 6, 9]
c = [3, 6, 9, 8, 10, 12]
```